# my script is set to current time but sheets still display as AM not PM

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

The script I am using is set to GMT+2 but somehow always sets to am when it is pm and vice versa.

I tried the data change component, and unit format but still doesn't work. Also made sure my sheet setting is set to Johannesburg time

```
function onEdit(e) {
  v`enter code here`ar TIME_ZONE = "GMT+2"; //enter desired timezone
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIME_ZONE, 'hh:mm:ss'); //enter 
  desired date format

  //if column A has been edited, set date in same row in column B
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 2).setValue(date);
  }
  }
```

The timestamp needs to be in South African time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the Timezone in the Script Editor. File > Project Properties. There is a Timezone Option you should see there as well.

Comment: It seems to jump back to the AM, as if my project settings in script doesn't want to save

Comment: Could the problem be here "  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIME_ZONE, 'hh:mm:ss');"

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your locale as well. try with:

[image: 0]